# is it possible to bind javascript and qtwidgets?

Tags: qt, qml

I have tested QML&javascript performance. It looks like works not very well if QML UI control is complex.
Just wonder if it is possible to bind javascript and qtwidgets?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following project that generates Qt bindings for Qt Script. I haven't tried it though.

https://code.google.com/p/qtscriptgenerator/

It is recommended that Javascript code should be kept to a minimum. Since it is bad for performance as you mentioned, especially when it is run during animation. I don't know what you are up to, but it would be better to implement UI with QML(minimum Javascript) and logic with Qt (C++).